# What data am I supposed to store into the "input_data" variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pandas

I'm supposed to pass preprocessed input to a TFLite model to make inferences. I have an excel file containing data and a tensorflowlite model file. I received instructions on how to do this; here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('excel_pathway_here')
import tensorflow as tf
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path = 'insert_tflite_file_here')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

#Assuming you have preprocessed your data (if needed) and stored it in a variable called input_data, you can now pass it to the TFLite model and make inferences

input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index']
output_index = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['index']
interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, input_data)
interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_index)
```

I'm a bit confused on the portion I've spaced out (and made the instructions to a comment). Is it saying I need to store the data file into input_data (which I already did on line 2)?

Answer (score 0):

In line 2, you are reading the excel file and storing it into a pandas dataframe. You need to change it into a format that is expected input type of tflite model (for e.g. you might need to change the datatype or dimension). 
See this example code for better understanding. 
[image]

*Picture taken from: https://notebook.community/tensorflow/examples/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_lite/tflite_c01_linear_regression*

Comment: So are the command lines for storing the excel data into input_data the lines up to "tflite_results = ..." in the second block of code you posted?

Comment: In 'input_shape = .........', they are storing the expected input size by the tflite model and then in, 'input_data = ........', they are making the input data of same size as expected by the model. 
For your case, you will have to convert 'data' of 2nd line into a format expected by the tflite model you are using.

Comment: No, you don't need all code lines of second block for yout purpose. For e.g., 'tflite_results = ....' is similar to 'output_data = ....' in your code. Get 'input_shape' for your tflite model, then declare variable 'input_data', changing 'data' into size 'input_shape'.